# How to create a new thread in accordance with specific conditions and join it later in C++11?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, join

```
std::thread main;
if (/*check code here*/)
{
main = std::thread(thread_hunt);
 }
main.join();
```

This code will cause an error while main thread join if it is not initialized in the if-statement.

```
bool i=false;
std::thread main;
if (/*check code here*/)
{
main = std::thread(thread_hunt);
j=true;
}
if (j)
{
main.join();
}
```

The code works well,but is there a easier way I can achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `joinable()` method on your thread object.

In your case:

```
std::thread main;
if (/*check code here*/)
{
    main = std::thread(thread_hunt);
}

if (main.joinable())
{
    main.join();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,this is exactly what I need .

Comment: @iouvxz Glad it helps =) You can accept an useful answer so that it gains visibility!